# Increase DB value if DB value equals 100

Tags: c#, asp.net

Got a DB table named Player, got the values Level SMALLINT and Experience SMALLINT + others. And i want to increase Level to 2 if Experience equals 50 or higher; I've tried this and a couple other things:

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand CheckStat = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Player WHERE UserID=@uid", connection);
    string uID = Session["userID"].ToString();
    CheckStat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uID);

    try
    {

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader StatReader = null;
        StatReader = CheckStat.ExecuteReader();


        if (StatReader.Read())
        {
            ExperienceLabel.Text = "Experience: " + StatReader["Experience"].ToString();
            EnergyLabel.Text = "Energy: " + StatReader["Energy"].ToString();
            GoldLabel.Text = "Gold: " + StatReader["Gold"].ToString();
            int Experience = Convert.ToInt32(StatReader["Experience"]);
            if (Experience >= 50)
            {
                SqlCommand Level2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Player SET player.Level=2 WHERE UserID=@uid", connection);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Level2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Error handling
                    LevelLabel.Text = (ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }


        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExperienceLabel.Text = (ex.Message);

    }
```

Comment: are you facing any error ??  whats your question?

Comment: why you used player.Level=2 insted of Level=2 in update query

Comment: Where do you set `@uid` in the `Level2` command?

Comment: No error, just nothing is happening :)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Will that carry over to the `Level2` SqlCommand object?

Comment: @DaveParsons indeed, I just saw the second command; good call - I suggest you make it an answer

Comment: @user3639988 let's hope they weren't level 72 when this happens, eh?

Comment: Tried to add Level2.Parameter.AddWithValue("@uid", uID); not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not providing your `SqlCommand Level2` with the `@uid` parameter.

Comment: Tried to add: Level2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uID); Still not working

Comment: What happens if you run the query directly against the DB?

Comment: Made a query with: UPDATE Player SET Level=2 WHERE Experience>50. It worked, still i want this to happen in game

Comment: What happens if you run the exact query from your code on the DB (subbing a valid `uid`)?

Comment: Will i be able to select the uid when im not logged in? The Session["UserId"]/@uid is the UserId of the account logged in.

Comment: paste `UPDATE Player SET player.Level=2 WHERE UserID=@uid` into SSMS and replace `@uid` with a valid id

Comment: UPDATE Player SET player.Level=3 WHERE UserID='6736ab66-d70c-4a7b-ad2a-d694f51095b2' AND Experience>150. Worked aswell.

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is that the code isn't doing what you think it is - debug, check each line and **every** variable *very* carefully.

Comment: **Every** variable is correct, but i wonder if the application cant update the database without pressing a button to activate it? This code is in Page_load.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting this in `Page_Load` but it wouldn't stop it from working correctly. I'm afraid at this point I'm stumped; sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: No problem, you've helped enough. Ill comment the answer when i find it!